# ConTeXt: Dynamic document metadata variables

Tags: macros, context, metadata, xml, xhtml

## Background

Looking to convert XHTML metadata into document variables.

## Code

The parts include:

- XHTML metadata -- includes user-defined metadata
- XML setups -- applies XML filters
- Metadata setups -- converts setups to document variables
- Document variables -- example variable usage

A short, self-contained, compilable example follows the parts explanation.

### XHTML metadata

Users may provide arbitrary document metadata through a GUI:

[image: document metadata user interface]

Users may then export the document as XHTML, which produces the following example XHTML header:

```html
<head>
  <title>Heuristic View of Light</title>
  <meta content="science, nature" name="keywords"/>
  <meta content="Milena Marić Einstein" name="author"/>
  <meta content="Albert Einstein" name="byline"/>
  <meta content="4500" name="count"/>
  <meta content="1905" name="copyright"/>
  <meta content="Annalen der Physik" name="journal"/>
</head>
```

Note that the metadata names will be sanitized for TeX-compatibility.

### XML setups

In the following XML setups, the first four have "special" behaviour, but the remainder are identical (save the name):

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:html
  % special setups
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/title/command(xml:title)}
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='author']/command(xml:author)}
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='byline']/command(xml:byline)}
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='keywords']/command(xml:keywords)}

  % virtually identical setups
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='address']/command(xml:address)}
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='phone']/command(xml:phone)}
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='email']/command(xml:email)}
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='count']/command(xml:count)}

  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups
```

### Metadata setups

The setups for the virtually identical metadata values follow the same pattern:

```tex
% create email document variable
\startxmlsetups xml:email
  \setupdocument[email={\xmlatt{#1}{content}}]
\stopxmlsetups

% create count document variable
\startxmlsetups xml:count
  \setupdocument[count={\xmlatt{#1}{content}}]
\stopxmlsetups
```

### Document variables

Here's an example usage of the document variables:

```tex
\startsetups document:start
  \starttitlemakeup
    \setupinterlinespace[line=14pt]

    {%
      \documentvariable{author}\hfill
      \TextNumberFormat{\documentvariable{count}} words
    }\break
    \documentvariable{address}\break
    \documentvariable{phone}\break
    \documentvariable{email}\break

    \vfill
    \startalignment[middle]
    \WORD{\documentvariable{title}}
    \blank[big]
    by
    \blank[big]
    \documentvariable{byline}
    \stopalignment
    \vfill
  \stoptitlemakeup
\stopsetups
```

In this fashion, users may define variables in the GUI, then reference them using the `\documentvariable{*}` macro.

### SSCCE

Here's a self-contained example demonstrating the issue:

```tex
\startbuffer[xdoc]
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="Milena Marić Einstein" name="author"/>
  <meta content="Annalen der Physik" name="journal"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{html|body}{xml:*}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{head}{xml:meta}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:xhtml}

\startxmlsetups xml:html
  \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='author']/command(xml:author)}

  % What goes here?
  %\xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='journal']/command(xml:journal)}

  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:author
  \setupdocument[author={\xmlatt{#1}{content}}]
  \setupdocument[metadata:author={\xmlatt{#1}{content}}]
  \setupinteraction[author={\documentvariable{author}}]
\stopxmlsetups

% How can this be generalized?
%\startxmlsetups xml:journal
  %\setupdocument[journal={\xmlatt{#1}{content}}]
%\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
  \startdocument
    Author: \documentvariable{author}

    \par

    Journal: \documentvariable{journal}
  \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{xdoc}{}
```

## Problem

Adding new metadata values (subtitle, volume, license, software, etc.) requires updating the XML setups and metadata setups, which is a step I'd like to avoid.

## Question

Given an XHTML document with arbitrary metadata `name` and `content` attributes, how would you automatically define document variables for each of the metadata names?

That is, given:

```html
<meta content="Annalen der Physik" name="journal"/>
```

How would you ensure the usage of:

```tex
\documentvariable{journal}
```

When both *journal* and *Annalen der Physik* can be defined arbitrarily by the user?

Comment: One thing that I have found useful while translating XML to TeX is to first convert XML data to a Lua tables and then just write Lua code to transform it however you want. See my talk at the context meeting: https://meeting.contextgarden.net/2021/talks/2021-09-24/xml-talk.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mailing list, define dynamic variables based on XHTML metadata as follows:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:setdocumentvariable
   \setupdocument[\xmlatt{#1}{name}={\xmlatt{#1}{content}}]
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:author
   \setupdocument[author={\xmlatt{#1}{content}}]
   \setupdocument[metadata:author={\xmlatt{#1}{content}}]
   \setupinteraction[author={\documentvariable{author}}]
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:html
   \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta/command(xml:setdocumentvariable)}
   \xmlfilter{#1}{/head/meta[@name='author']/command(xml:author)}

   \startdocument
     \xmlflush{#1}
   \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups
```

Note that by calling the `xmlfilter` for the `setdocumentvariable` command first, it affords the opportunity to customize specific metadata variables.